# SGD l2 penalty weights update

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

If you have stochastic gradient descent and you want to update the weights $w_t$ with the L2 norm regularization penalty, how is this math done? I am using sklearn for this and am just wondering how the weight $w_m$ is updated according to $l- \lambda||w||_{2}^{2}$. I read through the sklearn docs but they didn't go into to much detail about how this is actually performed mathematically.

Answer (score 8):

It's the same procedure as SGD with any other loss function. The only difference is that the loss function now has a penalty term added for $\ell_2$ regularization.

The standard SGD iteration for loss function $L(w)$ and step size $\alpha$ is:
$$w_{t+1} = w_t - \alpha \nabla_w L(w_t)$$

Say the original loss function was $L_0$, and you add a penalty term for $\ell_2$ regularization. The new loss function is:
$$L(w) = L_0(w) + \lambda \|w\|_2^2$$

The gradient is:
$$\nabla_w L(w)
= \nabla_w \left [ L_0(w) + \lambda \|w\|_2^2 \right ]
= \nabla_w L_0(w) + 2 \lambda w$$

Plug this into the SGD iteration above.

Comment: Is the last equation a _stochastic_ gradient, though? Suppose the loss is $L(w)=\sum_{n=1}^N f(x_i; w) + \lambda |w|^2$. _Stochastic_ gradient descent usually works with _averages_, so let's use $L_N(w)=L(w)/N=\frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N f(x_i; w) + \frac1N \lambda |w|^2 = \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N \left( f(x_i;w)+ \frac1N \lambda |w|^2\right)$. Now the stochastic gradient is $\nabla_w \left(f(x_i;w)+1/N \lambda |w|^2\right)$, which is $\nabla_w f(x_i;w)+2\lambda w/N$, so the regularization term should be divided by the sample size $N$.